# How do I calculate the % of a unique cell value for a group in another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
play_id game_id posteam defteam qtr down    time    yrdln   ydstogo desc    play_type
```

These are my columns. What I want to do is take each group under "posteam", find how many different times they ran a specific type of play under "play type"

so if my groups are "ari, chi, gb" then I want it to show me how many times each team ran a pass play and what the overall percentage of those are compared to the other play types.

```
plays.groupby('play_type')['play_type'].count()
```

Out[24]:

```
play_type
extra_point     1321
field_goal      1076
kickoff         2912
no_play         4718
pass           21010
punt            2187
qb_kneel         408
qb_spike          74
run            14756
Name: play_type, dtype: int64
```